# Submitting form but Jquery function not running to validate entries

Tags: jquery

The problem I am having is when I click the submit button the form is being submitted but the jquery is not running to validate that the submissions and check for valid entries. I thought that by adding the form="reservation_form" to the submit button this would resolve my issue, instead, it allowed the form to be submitted but not validated. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
"use strict"
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reservation_form").submit(function(event) {
      var isValid = true;
      var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
      var date = $("#dates").val().trim();
      $("#dates").val(date);
      if (date == "") {
        $("#dates").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        $("#dates").next().text("");
      }
      var nights = $("#nights").val().trim();
      $("#nights").val(nights);
      if (nights == "" || !$.isNumeric(nights)) {
        $("#nights").next().text("Please enter a number.");
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        $("#nights").next().text("");
      }
      var name = $("#name").val().trim();
      $("#name").val(name);
      if (name == "") {
        $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        $("#name").next().text("");
      }
      var email = $("#email").val().trim();
      if (email == "") {
        $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false;
      } else if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
        $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address");
      } else {
        $("#email").next().text("");
      }
      var phone = $("#phone").val().trim();
      $("#phone").val(phone);
      if (phone == "") {
        $("#phone").next().text("This field is required.");
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        $("#phone").next().text("");
      }
      if (isValid == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    } //end function
  ); //end submit 
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#dates").focus();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: +90,
    showButtonPanel: true
  }); //end datepicker function
  $("#book").button();
  $("#book").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      modal: true
    }); //end dialog
  }); // end click function
}); //end ready
```

```css
  header {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 4% 2%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.type {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

label.radiolabel {
  display: inline-block;
}

#dates {
  width: 16%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: none
}

input,
select {
  width: 16%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#dialog {
  display: none;
}

#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 65%;
}

#adult {
  width: 6%;
}

#children {
  width: 6%;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 35%;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

aside {
  margin-left: 30%;
}

aside button {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 2% 0 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  body {
    width: 85%;
  }
  #adult,
  #children {
    width: 15%;
  }
  #datepicker,
  #nights,
  #name,
  #email,
  #phone {
    width: 45%;
  }
  #tabs li {
    margin: 2%;
    width: 95%;
  }
  #tabs li a {
    padding-left: 35%;
  }
  .type {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  span {
    margin-left: 18%;
  }
  section {
    order: 1;
    margin: 0;
  }
  aside {
    order: 2;
    margin-left: 12%;
  }
  input,
  select {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
  }
  label {
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 30%;
  }
  aside button {
    width: 85%;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  h2 {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Chapter 10-11</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/reservationRequestWidget.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/reservationRequestWidget.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <form id="reservation_form" name="reservation_form" action="../submission.html" method="post">
        <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">General Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Preferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact Information</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div id="tabs-1">
            <label>Arrival Date:</label>
            <label id="dates"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></label><span>*</span><br>
            <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><span>*</span><br>
            <label for="adults">Adults:</label>
            <select name="adult" id="adult">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="children">Children:</label>
            <select name="children" id="children">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div id="tabs-2">
            <label class="type">Room Type:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" value="standard" checked>
            <label for="standard" class="radiolabel">Standard</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" value="business">
            <label for="business" class="radiolabel">Business</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" value="suite">
            <label for="suite" class="radiolabel">Suite</label><br>
            <label class="type">Bed Type:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" value="king" checked>
            <label for="king" class="radiolabel">King</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" value="double">
            <label for="double" class="radiolabel">Double</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="smoking" value="smoking">
            <label for="smoking" class="radiolabel">Smoking</label><br>
          </div>

          <div id="tabs-3">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span>*</span><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><span>*</span><br>
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
    <aside>
      <button onclick=w indow.location.href="../index.html">Home</button>
      <button onclick=w indow.location.href="../reservationRequest/reservationRequest.html">Reservation Request</button>
      <button onclick=w indow.location.href="../imageCarousel/imageCarousel.html">Image Carousel</button>
      <button><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" form="reservation_form"></button>
      <button id="book">Cancellation Policy</button>
      <div id="dialog" title="Cancellation Policy">
        Notification of cancellation or arrival date change must be received more than three days (72 hours) prior to the confirmed arrival date for the reservation deposit to be refundable. Email notification is acceptable, and a cancellation confirmation will
        be sent to you. Failure to check-in on the scheduled arrival date will result in the cancellation of the reservation including any remaining nights, and the reservation deposit shall be forfeited.
      </div>
    </aside>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You posted code is giving error `$(...).tabs is not a function` please add the related js file also to the code.

Comment: inside your jQuery event use `event.preventDefault()` on top;

Comment: .tabs comes from the jQuery UI 1.12.1 not sure how to add that here.

Comment: Thank you Ghanshyam. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Actually it made the jquery validate the entries fine but now the form will not submit once I have the entries filled out properly.

Answer (score 0):

If any part of your event handler has an error and throws an exception, `event.preventDefault()` won't be called and your form will submit.  You should wrap your event handler code in a `try { … } catch { … }` block to catch the errors and handle them.